# What components are absolute requirements for TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, exacttarget

I am working within ExactTarget which is a SalesForce subsidiary application and using their language AMPscript to create web forms which will update a Database table for use on publicly visible web pages. I want to use a wysiwyg Text Editor to allow non-coders to have more flexibility in editing these form "textarea" components. It was suggested I use TinyMCE. The challenge is that for this project I do not have an FTP accessible area to store the full set of application folders. In other instances I've been able to include only the required components of a .js and get the required functionality. 
I uploaded tinymce.min.js and placed the selector on the page. Without other components I don't see any text editing tools or a toolbar (nothing changed) on the still plain as day textarea. 
Am wondering if anyone knows the core and minimal set of files from within the plugins, themes, skins and langs directory that would be required. If it's only a few components I can rebuild it and probably edit the code to locate the files within ExactTarget. Otherwise it may simply be too complex an undertaking for this project.
Any other suggestions on resolving this are welcome.

Comment: FYI, there is a Salesforce stack exchange with an ExactTarget tag: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exacttarget .  You can get info directly from devs there.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are building this tool in an ExactTarget microsite/landing page, is there any reason why you can't just use the CDN for TinyMCE? From TinyMCE's documentation, you would only have to include the following lines to get an editor working in a textarea:

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
     });
</script>
```

If for some reason this is not an option, and you have to upload TinyMCE files to ExactTarget, it actually is possible to upload files to a hierarchy by selectively uploading files to the Portfolio and/or uploading files to a microsite using personalized URLs.